# How to transfer ebooks from Kindle account to PC?

Tags: kindle

I've bought an ebook on Amazon. I'd like to be able to read it offline on my PC. Also I hate being dependent on any external 'service' to read a book. So How can I download the ebook, if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calibre with Apprentice Alf's DeDRM tools (a separate plug-in) to read the book, after signing into Amazon >  Your Account > Manage Your Content and Devices. Then download to your computer and import into Calibre.

This answer is not to encourage stealing, only allowing you to read the content you 'purchased'

Calibre is available for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Transfer via Calibre**
Calibre is a opensource ebook library management which has many abilities such as managing ebook collections, converting ebook, sync to ebook reader devices such as Amazon Kindle, download news from the Internet and convert it to ebook friendly format, and more.

To use Calibre to transfer ebook to your Kindle device, please install it from Ubuntu repository, `sudo apt-get install calibre -y` should do that for you. Once installed, run Calibre and plug the Kindle devices. Calibre will automatically detect the Kindle and you are ready to go!
[image]
Once connected, you can add and remove ebook from Kindle, and also convert unsupported format into Kindle supported format.

**2. Direct transfer via File Manager**
If you don't need a complex method of transferring files (like Calibre does), you can transfer ebook via File manager. Please make sure there is no ebook manager software opened, plug in the Kindle, and File Manager should mount it automatically (like Thunar - XFCE File Manager - does).
[image]
All you need to do is put the ebook in "documents" folder. Please make sure that the ebooks you put in is supported by Kindle.

Comment: Thank you but I don't have a kindle device. Any solution for me?

Comment: Thst was just an example.